# How to bind an objects property to a Angular2 form item using select

Tags: angularjs, html, mongodb, angular, typescript

I have a problem with angular forms.
I am trying to create a form that uses data from a mongo collection and provides it via the  `<select>` directive.
I have a FormBuilder that is initialized like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        department_pk: ['', Validators.required],
        name_c: ['', Validators.required],
        location_fk: [],
        expirationdate_d: [],
    });
}
```

The Problem is the `location_fk` property. I am trying to fill the value of this property via the following `<select>` statement (I left the other form groups (for name_c, ...) out of this code snippet):

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm">                 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location (*): </label>
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="location_fk" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="select">
              <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of locations">{{i.name_c}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I managed to extract the value of `i`, however, I want to extract a property, `i.location_pk`, from the collection, while still displaying `i.name_c` in the selection that is visible for the user. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
<option [ngValue]="i['propName']" *ngFor="let i of locations">{{i.name_c}}</option>
```

or

```
<option [ngValue]="i.propName" *ngFor="let i of locations">{{i.name_c}}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! thought that i tried that already, kinda confused that didn´t work :P